# Many to many relationship in play with scala

Tags: scala, many-to-many, playframework, anorm

My question is fairly easy.

I have to model classes which are have a many-to-many relationship.

```
case class A(
     id: Pk[Long],
     name: String
)

case class B(
    id: Pk[Long],
    name: String
)
```

In play with java you can code this fairly easy, because of the Hibernate framework:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
public Set<A> allAs;
```

What is now the proper way in Play with Scala to add a many to many relationship between these two classes?

Do I have to model the helper table myself like this:

```
case class AToB(
    a_id: Long,
    b_id: Long
)
```

Or is there a better, easier way without the (unnecessary) code for the helper table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are probably using anorm, you have to do it yourself using the powers of sql, since anorm is not an orm

Comment: Pretty short answer. A little explanation would have been welcome.